# Prove: Graph with no induced C4 or P4 has an n-1 degree vertex

Tags: graph-theory

This is the question from **Fundamentals of domination in graphs-Marcel Dekker (1998)** page 39

[image]

I was wondering if this is true?

Comment: I am also wondering how this can work without the condition of the graph being connected.

Comment: It can't. The edgeless graph on $n\ge2 $ vertices has no $P_4$ or $C_4$ as induced subgraph ...

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen Exactly! Thats why I was confused. This theorem seems false thats why I posted it.

Comment: BTW, what is $\gamma$?

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen domination number: the minimum cardinality of a dominating set

Comment: Why is this true when the graph is connected?